# convert c#.net code into vb.net

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am a C# developer and working on a project with some parts written in VB.Net. I need to convert this C# code into VB.Net and one line is giving me some problems

Here is the code

```vb
 Process myProcess = new Process();
 myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\Adobe\Reader 11.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe";
 myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "/A \"page=10\" \"c:\\Classic\\Manual\\DocumentationManual.pdf\"";
 myProcess.Start();
```

Specifically the following line is giving me error

```vb
 myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "/A \"page=10\" \"c:\\Classic\\Manual\\DocumentationManual.pdf\"";
```

Can someone help in converting it correctly in VB.Net code. Online tools are not helping

Comment: I think in VB you dont escape characters, but you can do something like "" to give you a single quote in a string

Comment: Replace \\ with \ and \" with "" ([details](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa711651(v=vs.71).aspx)).

Comment: can you post the string over here after convert it into vb.net format ??

Comment: @puravtopiwala: You need to learn the basics of VB.Net strings.  We are not here to port your code for you.

Answer (score 3):

The escape characters are incorrect. The VB.NET code should look like this:

```vb
Dim myProcess As New Process()
myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\Program Files\Adobe\Reader 11.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe"
myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "/A ""page=10"" ""c:\Classic\Manual\DocumentationManual.pdf"""
myProcess.Start()
```

Comment: Thanks,its working well now.